# Error in using translator.translate from a list

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to use the google translator in python to translate my dataset to other language from a list of string

Then append the result in list

```
translated = []

for i in range(0,len(data)):
  try:
    translated.append(translator.translate((data[i]), src='en', dest= 'ms').text) 
  except:
    print ('')

print(translated)
```

However, the code print the exception. that is wrong

Comment: remove the `try:...  except:` structure and see what error is occuring

Comment: The error is 
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b178b644ce8f> in <module>()

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: You need to add some information about the "data" you used. It might be some weird character (maybe some quote marks or backslash) that is breaking your requests and you're recieving a decode error.

Comment: checked the data (data is stored in list). All the punctuation/url etc. already cleaned. Is it because there are numbers in data? But I tried run for string, instead of looping and it worked. But for looping, error came out

Comment: no result when removed try...except.. i guess the command for translator.translate() is wrong when looping?